# Changing the font size of multipanel Taylor plot using openair package in R

Tags: r, openair

I have created a multipanel Taylor plot using `openair` package. I want to change the font size of 'correlation' and 'observed' and make it sentence case. I have used the following code:

```
TaylorDiagram(data, obs = "Observed", mod = "Predicted", group = "Method", type = "Station")
```

[image]

Comment: could you please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can try out your code?

Comment: Just type ?TaylorDiagram after installing the 'openair' package. You will get the example code with dataset.

Comment: ok i checked the source code [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/openair/src/R/TaylorDiagram.R), i don't think it is possible to change the sentence case since it's a constant `"correlation"` also specific font sizes are not available, you just can change all font sizes with the `fontsize=` argument. Without rewriting the source code, i don't think it's possible. The diagramm doesn't support it by default

Comment: i also tried writing a new function with basis on the source code, but there are to many dependencies which i can't find all at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is now achieved by changing the source code of `TaylorDiagram` from `openair` package using the following code

```
library(lattice)
library(dplyr)

TaylorDiagram1 <- function(mydata, obs = "obs", mod = "mod", group = NULL, type = "default",
                           normalise = FALSE, cols = "brewer1",
                           rms.col = "darkgoldenrod", cor.col = "black", arrow.lwd = 3,
                           annotate = "centred\nRMS error",
                           key = TRUE, key.title = group, key.columns = 1,
                           key.pos = "right", strip = TRUE, auto.text = TRUE, ...) {

  ## get rid of R check annoyances
  sd.mod <- R <- NULL

  ## greyscale handling

  ## set graphics
  current.strip <- trellis.par.get("strip.background")
  current.font <- trellis.par.get("fontsize")

  ## reset graphic parameters
  on.exit(trellis.par.set(

    fontsize = current.font
  ))

  if (length(cols) == 1 && cols == "greyscale") {
    trellis.par.set(list(strip.background = list(col = "white")))
    ## other local colours
    method.col <- "greyscale"
  } else {
    method.col <- "default"
  }


  ## extra.args setup
  extra.args <- list(...)

  ## label controls (some local xlab, ylab management in code)
  extra.args$xlab <- if ("xlab" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    quickText(extra.args$xlab, auto.text)
  } else {
    NULL
  }

  extra.args$ylab <- if ("ylab" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    quickText(extra.args$ylab, auto.text)
  } else {
    NULL
  }

  extra.args$main <- if ("main" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    quickText(extra.args$main, auto.text)
  } else {
    quickText("", auto.text)
  }

  if ("fontsize" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    trellis.par.set(fontsize = list(text = extra.args$fontsize))
  }


  if (!"layout" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$layout <- NULL
  }


  if (!"pch" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$pch <- 20
  }

  if (!"cex" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$cex <- 2
  }

  ## #######################################################################################

  ## check to see if two data sets are present
  combine <- FALSE

  if (length(mod) == 2) combine <- TRUE

  if (any(type %in% dateTypes)) {
    vars <- c("date", obs, mod)
  } else {
    vars <- c(obs, mod)
  }

  ## assume two groups do not exist
  twoGrp <- FALSE

  if (!missing(group)) if (any(group %in% type)) stop("Can't have 'group' also in 'type'.")

  mydata <- cutData(mydata, type, ...)

  if (missing(group)) {
    if ((!"group" %in% type) & (!"group" %in% c(obs, mod))) {
      mydata$group <- factor("group")
      group <- "group"
      npol <- 1
    }
    ## don't overwrite a
  } else { ## means that group is there
    mydata <- cutData(mydata, group, ...)
  }

  ## if group is present, need to add that list of variables unless it is
  ## a pre-defined date-based one
  if (!missing(group)) {
    npol <- length(unique((mydata[[group[1]]])))

    ## if group is of length 2
    if (length(group) == 2L) {
      twoGrp <- TRUE
      grp1 <- group[1]
      grp2 <- group[2]

      if (missing(key.title)) key.title <- grp1
      vars <- c(vars, grp1, grp2)
      mydata$newgrp <- paste(mydata[[group[1]]], mydata[[group[2]]], sep = "-")
      group <- "newgrp"
    }

    if (group %in% dateTypes | any(type %in% dateTypes)) {
      vars <- unique(c(vars, "date", group))
    } else {
      vars <- unique(c(vars, group))
    }
  }

  ## data checks, for base and new data if necessary

  mydata <- checkPrep(mydata, vars, type)

  # check mod and obs are numbers
  mydata <- checkNum(mydata, vars = c(obs, mod))

  ## remove missing data
  mydata <- na.omit(mydata)

  legend <- NULL

  ## function to calculate stats for TD
  calcStats <- function(mydata, obs = obs, mod = mod) {
    R <- cor(mydata[[obs]], mydata[[mod]], use = "pairwise")
    sd.obs <- sd(mydata[[obs]])
    sd.mod <- sd(mydata[[mod]])
    if (normalise) {
      sd.mod <- sd.mod / sd.obs
      sd.obs <- 1
    }

    res <- data.frame(R, sd.obs, sd.mod)
    res
  }

  vars <- c(group, type)

  results <- group_by(mydata, UQS(syms(vars))) %>%
    do(calcStats(., obs = obs, mod = mod[1]))

  results.new <- NULL

  if (combine) {
    results.new <- group_by(mydata, UQS(syms(vars))) %>%
      do(calcStats(., obs = obs, mod = mod[2]))
  }


  ## if no group to plot, then add a dummy one to make xyplot work
  if (is.null(group)) {
    results$MyGroupVar <- factor("MyGroupVar")
    group <- "MyGroupVar"
  }

  ## set up colours
  myColors <- openColours(cols, npol)
  pch.orig <- extra.args$pch

  ## combined colours if two groups
  if (twoGrp) {
    myColors <- rep(
      openColours(cols, length(unique(mydata[[grp1]]))),
      each = length(unique(mydata[[grp2]]))
    )

    extra.args$pch <- rep(extra.args$pch, each = length(unique(mydata[[grp2]])))
  }

  ## basic function for lattice call + defaults
  temp <- paste(type, collapse = "+")

  myform <- formula(paste("R ~ sd.mod", "|", temp, sep = ""))

  scales <- list(x = list(rot = 0), y = list(rot = 0))

  pol.name <- sapply(levels(mydata[, group]), function(x) quickText(x, auto.text))


  if (key & npol > 1 & !combine) {
    thecols <- unique(myColors)
    if (twoGrp) {
      pol.name <- levels(factor(mydata[[grp1]]))
    }

    key <- list(
      points = list(col = thecols), pch = pch.orig,
      cex = extra.args$cex, text = list(lab = pol.name, cex = 0.8),
      space = key.pos, columns = key.columns,
      title = quickText(key.title, auto.text),
      cex.title = 0.8, lines.title = 3
    )
  } else if (key & npol > 1 & combine) {
    key <- list(
      lines = list(col = myColors[1:npol]), lwd = arrow.lwd,
      text = list(lab = pol.name, cex = 0.8), space = key.pos,
      columns = key.columns,
      title = quickText(key.title, auto.text),
      cex.title = 0.8, lines.title = 3
    )
  } else {
    key <- NULL
  }


  ## special wd layout
  if (length(type) == 1 & type[1] == "wd" & is.null(extra.args$layout)) {
    ## re-order to make sensible layout
    wds <- c("NW", "N", "NE", "W", "E", "SW", "S", "SE")
    mydata$wd <- ordered(mydata$wd, levels = wds)
    ## see if wd is actually there or not
    wd.ok <- sapply(wds, function(x) {
      if (x %in% unique(mydata$wd)) FALSE else TRUE
    })
    skip <- c(wd.ok[1:4], TRUE, wd.ok[5:8])
    mydata$wd <- factor(mydata$wd) ## remove empty factor levels
    extra.args$layout <- c(3, 3)
    if (!"skip" %in% names(extra.args)) {
      extra.args$skip <- skip
    }
  }
  if (!"skip" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$skip <- FALSE
  }


  ## proper names of labelling ####################################################

  stripName <- sapply(levels(mydata[, type[1]]), function(x) quickText(x, auto.text))
  if (strip) strip <- strip.custom(factor.levels = stripName)

  if (length(type) == 1) {
    strip.left <- FALSE
  } else { ## two conditioning variables
    stripName <- sapply(levels(mydata[, type[2]]), function(x) quickText(x, auto.text))
    strip.left <- strip.custom(factor.levels = stripName)
  }
  ## #############################################################################


  ## no strip needed for single panel
  if (length(type) == 1 & type[1] == "default") strip <- FALSE

  ## not sure how to evaluate "group" in xyplot, so change to a fixed name
  id <- which(names(results) == group)
  names(results)[id] <- "MyGroupVar"

  maxsd <- 1.2 * max(results$sd.obs, results$sd.mod)

  # xlim, ylim handling
  if (!"ylim" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$ylim <- 1.12 * c(0, maxsd)
  }
  if (!"xlim" %in% names(extra.args)) {
    extra.args$xlim <- 1.12 * c(0, maxsd)
  }

  ## xlab, ylab local management
  if (is.null(extra.args$ylab)) {
    extra.args$ylab <- if (normalise) "standard deviation (normalised)" else "Standard deviation"
  }
  if (is.null(extra.args$xlab)) {
    extra.args$xlab <- extra.args$ylab
  }


  ## plot
  xyplot.args <- list(
    x = myform, data = results, groups = results$MyGroupVar,
    aspect = 1,
    type = "n",
    as.table = TRUE,
    scales = scales,
    key = key,
    par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.8),
    strip = strip,
    strip.left = strip.left,
    panel = function(x, y, ...) {

      ## annotate each panel but don't need to do this for each grouping value
      panel.taylor.setup(
        x, y,
        results = results, maxsd = maxsd,
        cor.col = cor.col, rms.col = rms.col,
        annotate = annotate, ...
      )

      ## plot data in each panel
      panel.superpose(
        x, y,
        panel.groups = panel.taylor, ...,
        results = results, results.new = results.new,
        combine = combine, myColors = myColors,
        arrow.lwd = arrow.lwd
      )
    }
  )

  ## reset for extra.args
  xyplot.args <- listUpdate(xyplot.args, extra.args)

  ## plot
  plt <- do.call(xyplot, xyplot.args)


  if (length(type) == 1) plot(plt) else plot(useOuterStrips(plt, strip = strip, strip.left = strip.left))
  newdata <- results
  output <- list(plot = plt, data = newdata, call = match.call())
  class(output) <- "openair"


  invisible(output)
}


panel.taylor.setup <- function(x, y, subscripts, results, maxsd, cor.col, rms.col,
                               col.symbol, annotate, group.number, type, ...) {
  ## note, this assumes for each level of type there is a single measured value
  ## therefore, only the first is used  i.e. results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]]
  ## This does not matter if normalise = TRUE because all sd.obs = 1.

  ## The data frame 'results' should contain a grouping variable 'MyGroupVar',
  ## 'type' e.g. season, R (correlation coef), sd.obs and sd.mod
  xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi / 2, by = 0.01)) * maxsd
  ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi / 2, by = 0.01)) * maxsd
  llines(xcurve, ycurve, col = "black")

  xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi / 2, by = 0.01)) * results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]]
  ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi / 2, by = 0.01)) * results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]]
  llines(xcurve, ycurve, col = "black", lty = 5)

  corr.lines <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9)

  ## grid line with alpha transparency
  theCol <- t(col2rgb(cor.col)) / 255

  for (gcl in corr.lines) llines(
    c(0, maxsd * gcl), c(0, maxsd * sqrt(1 - gcl ^ 2)),
    col = rgb(theCol, alpha = 0.4), alpha = 0.5
  )

  bigtick <- acos(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1))
  medtick <- acos(seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.1))
  smltick <- acos(seq(0.91, 0.99, by = 0.01))

  lsegments(
    cos(bigtick) * maxsd, sin(bigtick) *
      maxsd, cos(bigtick) * 0.96 * maxsd, sin(bigtick) * 0.96 * maxsd,
    col = cor.col
  )

  lsegments(
    cos(medtick) * maxsd, sin(medtick) *
      maxsd, cos(medtick) * 0.98 * maxsd, sin(medtick) * 0.98 * maxsd,
    col = cor.col
  )
  lsegments(
    cos(smltick) * maxsd, sin(smltick) *
      maxsd, cos(smltick) * 0.99 * maxsd, sin(smltick) * 0.99 * maxsd,
    col = cor.col
  )

  ## arcs for standard deviations (3 by default)
  gamma <- pretty(c(0, maxsd), n = 5)
  if (gamma[length(gamma)] > maxsd) {
    gamma <- gamma[-length(gamma)]
  }
  labelpos <- seq(45, 70, length.out = length(gamma))

  ## some from plotrix
  for (gindex in 1:length(gamma)) {
    xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi, by = 0.03)) * gamma[gindex] +
      results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]]
    endcurve <- which(xcurve < 0)
    endcurve <- ifelse(length(endcurve), min(endcurve) - 1, 105)
    ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi, by = 0.03)) * gamma[gindex]
    maxcurve <- xcurve * xcurve + ycurve * ycurve
    startcurve <- which(maxcurve > maxsd * maxsd)
    startcurve <- ifelse(length(startcurve), max(startcurve) + 1, 0)

    llines(
      xcurve[startcurve:endcurve], ycurve[startcurve:endcurve],
      col = rms.col, lty = 5
    )
    ltext(
      xcurve[labelpos[gindex]], ycurve[labelpos[gindex]],
      gamma[gindex],
      cex = 0.7, col = rms.col, pos = 1,
      srt = 0, font = 2
    )

    ltext(
      1.1 * maxsd, 1.05 * maxsd,
      labels = annotate, cex = 0.7,
      col = rms.col, pos = 2
    )
  }

  ## angles for R key
  angles <- 180 * c(bigtick, acos(c(0.95, 0.99))) / pi

  ltext(
    cos(c(bigtick, acos(c(0.95, 0.99)))) *
      1.06 * maxsd, sin(c(bigtick, acos(c(0.95, 0.99)))) *
      1.06 * maxsd, c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), 0.95, 0.99),
    cex = 0.7,
    adj = 0.5, srt = angles, col = cor.col
  )

  ltext(
    0.82 * maxsd, 0.82 * maxsd, "Correlation",
    srt = 315, cex = 0.7,
    col = cor.col
  )


  ## measured point and text
  lpoints(results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]], 0, pch = 20, col = "purple", cex = 1.5)
  ltext(results$sd.obs[subscripts[1]], 0, "Observed", col = "purple", cex = 0.7, pos = 3)
}


panel.taylor <- function(x, y, subscripts, results, results.new, maxsd, cor.col,
                         rms.col, combine, col.symbol, myColors, group.number,
                         type, arrow.lwd, ...) {
  R <- NULL
  sd.mod <- NULL ## avoid R NOTEs

  ## Plot actual results by type and group if given
  results <- transform(results, x = sd.mod * R, y = sd.mod * sin(acos(R)))

  if (combine) {
    results.new <- transform(results.new, x = sd.mod * R, y = sd.mod * sin(acos(R)))
    larrows(
      results$x[subscripts], results$y[subscripts],
      results.new$x[subscripts], results.new$y[subscripts],
      angle = 30, length = 0.1, col = myColors[group.number], lwd = arrow.lwd
    )
  } else {
    lpoints(
      results$x[subscripts], results$y[subscripts],
      col.symbol = myColors[group.number], ...
    )
  }
}

startYear <- function(dat) as.numeric(format(min(dat[order(dat)]), "%Y"))
endYear <- function(dat) as.numeric(format(max(dat[order(dat)]), "%Y"))
startMonth <- function(dat) as.numeric(format(min(dat[order(dat)]), "%m"))
endMonth <- function(dat) as.numeric(format(max(dat[order(dat)]), "%m"))

## these are pre-defined type that need a field "date"; used by cutData
dateTypes <- c("year", "hour", "month", "season", "weekday", "weekend",
               "monthyear", "gmtbst", "bstgmt", "dst", "daylight",
               "seasonyear", "yearseason")


checkPrep <- function(mydata, Names, type, remove.calm = TRUE, remove.neg = TRUE,
                      strip.white = TRUE, wd = "wd") {

  ## deal with conditioning variable if present, if user-defined, must exist in data
  ## pre-defined types
  ## existing conditioning variables that only depend on date (which is checked)
  conds <- c(
    "default", "year", "hour", "month", "season", "weekday",
    "weekend", "monthyear", "gmtbst", "bstgmt", "dst", "daylight",
    "yearseason", "seasonyear"
  )
  all.vars <- unique(c(names(mydata), conds))

  varNames <- c(Names, type) ## names we want to be there
  matching <- varNames %in% all.vars

  if (any(!matching)) {
    ## not all variables are present
    stop(cat("Can't find the variable(s)", varNames[!matching], "\n"))
  }

  ## add type to names if not in pre-defined list
  if (any(type %in% conds == FALSE)) {
    ids <- which(type %in% conds == FALSE)
    Names <- c(Names, type[ids])
  }

  ## if type already present in data frame
  if (any(type %in% names(mydata))) {
    ids <- which(type %in% names(mydata))
    Names <- unique(c(Names, type[ids]))
  }

  ## just select data needed
  mydata <- mydata[, Names]

  ## if site is in the data set, check none are missing
  ## seems to be a problem for some KCL data...
  if ("site" %in% names(mydata)) { ## split by site

    ## remove any NA sites
    if (anyNA(mydata$site)) {
      id <- which(is.na(mydata$site))
      mydata <- mydata[-id, ]
    }
  }


  ## sometimes ratios are considered which can results in infinite values
  ## make sure all infinite values are set to NA
  mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) {
    replace(x, x == Inf | x == -Inf, NA)
  })

  if ("ws" %in% Names) {
    if ("ws" %in% Names & is.numeric(mydata$ws)) {

      ## check for negative wind speeds
      if (any(sign(mydata$ws[!is.na(mydata$ws)]) == -1)) {
        if (remove.neg) { ## remove negative ws only if TRUE
          warning("Wind speed <0; removing negative data")
          mydata$ws[mydata$ws < 0] <- NA
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ## round wd to make processing obvious
  ## data already rounded to nearest 10 degress will not be affected
  ## data not rounded will be rounded to nearest 10 degrees
  ## assumes 10 is average of 5-15 etc
  if (wd %in% Names) {
    if (wd %in% Names & is.numeric(mydata[, wd])) {

      ## check for wd <0 or > 360
      if (any(sign(mydata[[wd]][!is.na(mydata[[wd]])]) == -1 |
              mydata[[wd]][!is.na(mydata[[wd]])] > 360)) {
        warning("Wind direction < 0 or > 360; removing these data")
        mydata[[wd]][mydata[[wd]] < 0] <- NA
        mydata[[wd]][mydata[[wd]] > 360] <- NA
      }

      if (remove.calm) {
        if ("ws" %in% names(mydata)) {
          mydata[[wd]][mydata$ws == 0] <- NA ## set wd to NA where there are calms
          mydata$ws[mydata$ws == 0] <- NA ## remove calm ws
        }
        mydata[[wd]][mydata[[wd]] == 0] <- 360 ## set any legitimate wd to 360

        ## round wd for use in functions - except windRose/pollutionRose
        mydata[[wd]] <- 10 * ceiling(mydata[[wd]] / 10 - 0.5)
        mydata[[wd]][mydata[[wd]] == 0] <- 360 # angles <5 should be in 360 bin
      }
      mydata[[wd]][mydata[[wd]] == 0] <- 360 ## set any legitimate wd to 360
    }
  }


  ## make sure date is ordered in time if present
  if ("date" %in% Names) {
    if ("POSIXlt" %in% class(mydata$date)) {
      stop("date should be in POSIXct format not POSIXlt")
    }

    ## if date in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (basic check)
    if (length(grep("/", as.character(mydata$date[1]))) > 0) {
      mydata$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(mydata$date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), "GMT")
    }

    ## try and work with a factor date - but probably a problem in original data
    if (is.factor(mydata$date)) {
      warning("date field is a factor, check date format")
      mydata$date <- as.POSIXct(mydata$date, "GMT")
    }

    mydata <- arrange(mydata, date)

    ## make sure date is the first field
    if (names(mydata)[1] != "date") {
      mydata <- mydata[c("date", setdiff(names(mydata), "date"))]
    }

    ## check to see if there are any missing dates, stop if there are
    ids <- which(is.na(mydata$date))
    if (length(ids) > 0) {
      mydata <- mydata[-ids, ]
      warning(paste(
        "Missing dates detected, removing",
        length(ids), "lines"
      ), call. = FALSE)
    }

    ## daylight saving time can cause terrible problems - best avoided!!

    if (any(dst(mydata$date))) {
      warning("Detected data with Daylight Saving Time, converting to UTC/GMT")
      mydata$date <- lubridate::force_tz(mydata$date, tzone = "GMT")
    }
  }




  if (strip.white) {
    ## set panel strip to white
    suppressWarnings(trellis.par.set(list(strip.background = list(col = "white"))))
  }


  ## return data frame
  return(mydata)
}

# function to check variables are numeric, if not force with warning
checkNum <- function(mydata, vars) {
  for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
    if (!is.numeric(mydata[[vars[i]]])) {
      mydata[[vars[i]]] <- as.numeric(as.character(mydata[[vars[i]]]))

      warning(
        paste(vars[i], "is not numeric, forcing to numeric..."),
        call. = FALSE
      )
    }
  }

  return(mydata)
}

## listUpdate function
# [in development]
listUpdate <- function(a, b, drop.dots = TRUE,
                       subset.a = NULL, subset.b = NULL) {
  if (drop.dots) {
    a <- a[names(a) != "..."]
    b <- b[names(b) != "..."]
  }
  if (!is.null(subset.a)) {
    a <- a[names(a) %in% subset.a]
  }
  if (!is.null(subset.b)) {
    b <- b[names(b) %in% subset.b]
  }
  if (length(names(b) > 0)) {
    a <- modifyList(a, b)
  }
  a
}
```

Then use the following code for plotting

```
 TaylorDiagram1(data, obs = "Observed", mod = "Predicted", group = "Method", type = "Station",
                  scales=list(alternating=1),normalise = TRUE,fontsize=12,
                  rms.col="black",auto.text=F,xlab="Standard deviation",
                  cex = 1, ylab="Standard deviation",par.settings = list( grid.pars = list(fontfamily = "serif")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bappa Das for sharing the modified script.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the size of all the text in `openair` Taylor diagram, you can do the following.

```r
library(openair)

# built-in dataset
head(mydata)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   date                   ws    wd   nox   no2    o3  pm10   so2    co  pm25
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 1998-01-01 00:00:00  0.6    280   285    39     1    29  4.72  3.37    NA
#> 2 1998-01-01 01:00:00  2.16   230    NA    NA    NA    37 NA    NA       NA
#> 3 1998-01-01 02:00:00  2.76   190    NA    NA     3    34  6.83  9.60    NA
#> 4 1998-01-01 03:00:00  2.16   170   493    52     3    35  7.66 10.2     NA
#> 5 1998-01-01 04:00:00  2.4    180   468    78     2    34  8.07  8.91    NA
#> 6 1998-01-01 05:00:00  3      190   264    42     0    16  5.50  3.05    NA

## dummy model data for 2003
dat <- selectByDate(mydata, year = 2003)
dat <- data.frame(date = mydata$date, obs = mydata$nox, mod = mydata$nox)

## now make mod worse by adding bias and noise according to the month
## do this for 3 different models
dat  <- transform(dat, month = as.numeric(format(date, "%m")))
mod1 <- transform(dat, mod = mod + 10 * month + 10 * month * rnorm(nrow(dat)),
                  model = "model 1")
## lag the results for mod1 to make the correlation coefficient worse
## without affecting the sd
mod1 <- transform(mod1, mod = c(mod[5:length(mod)], mod[(length(mod) - 3) :
                                                          length(mod)]))
## model 2
mod2 <- transform(dat, mod = mod + 7 * month + 7 * month * rnorm(nrow(dat)),
                  model = "model 2")
## model 3
mod3 <- transform(dat, mod = mod + 3 * month + 3 * month * rnorm(nrow(dat)),
                  model = "model 3")
mod.dat <- rbind(mod1, mod2, mod3)
str(mod.dat)
#> 'data.frame':    196599 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ date : POSIXct, format: "1998-01-01 00:00:00" "1998-01-01 01:00:00" ...
#>  $ obs  : int  285 NA NA 493 468 264 171 195 137 113 ...
#>  $ mod  : num  486 275 177 219 144 ...
#>  $ month: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ model: chr  "model 1" "model 1" "model 1" "model 1" ...
head(mod.dat)
#>                  date obs      mod month   model
#> 1 1998-01-01 00:00:00 285 486.3062     1 model 1
#> 2 1998-01-01 01:00:00  NA 274.8424     1 model 1
#> 3 1998-01-01 02:00:00  NA 177.3958     1 model 1
#> 4 1998-01-01 03:00:00 493 219.2187     1 model 1
#> 5 1998-01-01 04:00:00 468 144.3721     1 model 1
#> 6 1998-01-01 05:00:00 264 105.5251     1 model 1

TaylorDiagram(mod.dat, 
              obs = "obs", 
              mod = "mod", 
              group = "model",  
              type = "season",
              main = "Taylor Diagram",
              xlab = "Standard Deviation", 
              ylab = "Standard Deviation",
              par.settings = list(par.main.text = list(font = 2, 
                                                       just = "left", 
                                                       x = grid::unit(5, "mm")),
                                  fontsize = list(text = 18)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>